# Vim does not open Git branch files

Tags: git

I checkout an old git commit as a branch, with:

```
git checkout -b b48cdaa
```

Then I open vim (actually Macvim) and I expect to see the files from the old commit, but all the files are the current (master branch) rev. Why is that? How can I look at an old rev in vim?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout -b b48cdaa
```

is creating a new branch called b48cdaa in your case referencing the current HEAD.

What you probably want to do is

```
git checkout -b branch_name b48cdaa
```

.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing what you think you're doing.  `git checkout -b b48cdaa` creates a *new branch* named "b48cdaa".

If you drop the `-b`, it should checkout the commit with the specified sha1 (and leave you in "detached head" state).

`git checkout --help` for more information.

(Note that this has nothing to do with vim.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the man, it seems the -b flag does not what you expect :

```
 git checkout [-q] [-f] [-m] [[-b|-B|--orphan] <new_branch>] [<start_point>]

-b
           Create a new branch named <new_branch> and start it at <start_point>; see git-branch(1)
           for details.
```

You just created a new branch named b48cdaa holding the new files.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Git documentation (for the checkout command) :

> **-b** Create a new branch named  and start it at ; see git-branch(1) for details.

Just tape `git checkout b48cdaa`

**But be careful**

When you do this, you change the HEAD to the commit b48cdaa. My advice is to tape this command in another branch. So :

```
git checkout -b test_branch
git checkout b48cdaa
```

And when you are ready to return to the original head :

```
git checkout master
```

(if you want to remove the test_branch :

```
git branch -d test_branch
```

)